# yum list-security no longer reports package as needing security update

Tags: security, yum

We have an audit system that, daily, tracks packages in need of a security update using:

```
yum list-security --security -q 2
```

For better or worse, some machines are not patched timely or missed, or are offline for some time. Many machines, to minimize possible issues, will just get security patches applied and this is where things go off the rails a bit.

It seems if there is a newer release of a package that is no longer attached to a security bulletin, packages are not getting updated, when doing a `yum update-minimal --security`

```
clamav-0.99.4-1.el7 - installed
clamav-0.100.2-2.el7 - yum list-security (around 11/2018): 
clam-0.101.1-1.el7 - current available (not shown in yum list-security)
```

Am I missing something, or should `yum list-security` still show this as a package in need of a security update? Or is this just a limitation of how `yum list-security` works and our auditing is more correct than the package manager?

Comment: The man pages don't seem to have any info for `list-security`, but it does have info on `--security` which is what I have always used. Try `yum check-update --security` for a list of packages that report they are security-related updates. Be warned, the output is quite extensive, but the summary at the end is the number of updates that comply with the `--security` query, out of the total available, and a list of the actual security updates in question.

Answer (score 0):

The command `yum list-security --security` work only on RHEL 5.

On RHEL 7 , you should use the following commands:

> ```
> # yum updateinfo list security all
> # yum updateinfo list sec
> ```

redhat:  [Is it possible to limit yum so that it lists or installs only security updates?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10021)